# How to I create a Dock menu for my AppleScript application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, macos-catalina

I just created an application with AppleScript, and I would like to create custom menu items for its Dock menu, as shown in the image below. How do I do that?

I'm somewhat familiar with AppleScript, so it would be nice if someone could show me how to add a menu item that triggers an AppleScript script.

[image: Dock Menu]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways.  One is to use the **Interface Editor** to build a menu and connect it to your app's `dockMenu` outlet.  Another is to add the `applicationDockMenu:` method from the **NSApplicationDelegate** class to your application delegate.  In this handler you just create your menu and return it - it will be added to the Dock menu when it is shown.

For a single script document using some **AppleScriptObjC**, you will also need to tell the system what the delegate is, so a statement can be added to the `run` handler.  A complete application would then be something like:

```
use framework "Cocoa"
use scripting additions

on run -- example
    tell current application's NSApp to set its delegate to me
    -- other setup stuff
end run

on applicationDockMenu:sender -- return a menu to be added to the Dock menu
    tell (current application's NSMenu's alloc's initWithTitle:"")
        its addItem:(current application's NSMenuItem's alloc's initWithTitle:"Item One" action:"myMenuAction:" keyEquivalent:"")
        its addItem:(current application's NSMenuItem's alloc's initWithTitle:"Item Two" action:"myMenuAction:" keyEquivalent:"")
        return it
    end tell
end applicationDockMenu:

on myMenuAction:sender -- a regular action handler
    display dialog (sender's title) as text
    -- additional script stuff
end sharedAction:
```

**EDIT**

It doesn't look like the single document script works very well for this, my example crashes when quitting.  I've tested with a Cocoa-AppleScript Applet though, and it does work, although there are a few different files to mess with.

For an application built using a `Cocoa-AppleScript Applet` Template from the Script Editor, you can put the dockMenu and action handlers in the `CocoaAppletAppDelegate` script in the bundle.

Comment: I've never used XCode before, so most of that went over my head. I created this app in AppleScript and then exported it to an application. XCode doesn't appear to be able to open it. What do I do? @red_menace

Comment: What I would like to do is to be able to trigger an AppleScript when an item is clicked on. I would be totally lost in XCode

Comment: I edited my answer for an application from the Script Editor (don't forget to save it as stay-open).  You can use different action handlers to handle the menu items as desired.

Comment: When I run this, it adds an item to the Script Editor application itself. How do I change this to the application of my choice, and how do I trigger some AppleScript code when the item is clicked on? BTW, thanks for all the help, I didn't know you could do this from within applescript @red_menace

Comment: You will need to save the script as its own application.  I noticed that a simple script crashes on quitting, but a Cocoa-AppleScript from the built-in template works.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, I saved the script as it's own application. But where do I add additional code that I want to run? Also, I still can't figure out how to make the dock bar items trigger commands when I click on them. Also, do the custom dock items only appear when the application is running, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Each menu has an action handler - in my example, it is `myMenuAction`.  You can use a single action and check the menu title, or use a separate action for each menu item.  The menu items only appear when you click on the Dock icon, so the application does need to be running.